# Why do I receive this email 3 days late?

Tags: email, email-server

Somebody (SomebodyThere@icbm.de) sent me an email on 8th Sept and I received it only on 11th Sept.
Can anyone shed some light why?

These are the headers:

```
From - Fri Sep 11 11:27:52 2015
X-Account-Key: account6
X-UIDL: UID38-13942566
X-Mozilla-Status: 0000
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
Return-path: <SomebodyThere@icbm.de>
Envelope-to: Me@MyEmailAddress.com
Delivery-date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 03:19:36 -0600
Received: from [x.x.101.100] (port=52283 helo=smtp110.uni-oldenburg.de)
    by box95.bluehost.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA38:256)
    (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <SomebodyThere@icbm.de>)
    id 1ZF3w-04Ok-2c
    for Me@MyEmailAddress.com; Tue, 08 Sep 2015 03:19:36 -0600
Received: from smtp.uni-oldenburg.de (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (Email Security Appliance) with SMTP id 5D43890E_5EEA3B
    for <Me@MyEmailAddress.com>; Tue,  8 Sep 2015 09:19:31 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from [x.x.80.9] (hp.icbm.uni-oldenburg.de [x.x.80.90])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (Client did not present a certificate)
    by smtp110.uni-oldenburg.de (Sophos Email Appliance) with ESMTPSA id 02A0190B_5EEA83F
    for <Me@MyEmailAddress.com>; Tue,  8 Sep 2015 09:19:31 +0000 (GMT)
Message-ID: <55EEAB.5000702@icbm.de>
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 11:19:55 +0200
From: <SomebodyThere@icbm.de>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20110624 Thunderbird/5.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: <Me@MyEmailAddress.com>
Subject: Re: Hi again
References: <5591F.2xxx@icbm.de> <55ED62.1xxx@MyEmailAddress>
In-Reply-To: <55E2D9.1xxx@MyEmailAddress>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------0209070105040904070600"
X-Identified-User: {0000:box95.bluehost.com:local:local} {sentby:Delivered locally}
```

Comment: As an advice of security you would like to obfuscate IPs addresses in such a mail.

Comment: @Gopoi-Thanks. I already cut/changed numbers in the IP and and ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the email and assuming all relay actually appended a Received: field. The mail was properly received by your bluehost server on 03:19:55 -0600 within seconds of being sent. As shown by line:

> Received: from [x.x.101.100] (port=52283 helo=smtp110.uni-oldenburg.de)
>       by box95.bluehost.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA38:256)
>       (Exim 4.84)
>       (envelope-from )
>       id 1ZF3w-04Ok-2c
>       for Me@MyEmailAddress.com; Tue, 08 Sep 2015 03:19:36 -0600

So I would check if your receiving end has any delay to fetch mail or that the server that receives the mail did not put in a long anti-spam check.

I would pull out the logs from your mail server at that moment to see what happened wrong. If the header is right you should look at 2015-09-08 03:19  -0600 (your servers local time).

Comment: Then, what is the first line: "From - Fri Sep 11 11:27:52 2015". What does it mean?

Comment: 'My' server (BlueHost) usually receives emails from all over the world in seconds. I send emails to myself from gmail. No email lost. Ever! Also I disabled their anti-spam filter as soon as I purchased their (BlueHost) services. Only the emails from this user have a problem.

Comment: Where have you pulled this header from the first line seems to be added by something, it is not in standard MIME format....Which is even more confusing.

Comment: I got the header directly from Thunderbird (Ctrl+U). And that's the date when I actually received the message.

Comment: Could your thunderbird have a sender specific rule that delays email retrival (if that is even possible)? Or does the server not put it in your mailbox for some reasons?

Comment: First one: no. I don't know about the second one. The server also does not have a specific rule to read the email later, but if something went wrong... a hang... I don;t know. maybe it got the emails later...